# Connection Class to connect Oracle DB with Android Studio Project

Tags: java, android

I used to connect my Android Studio to Microsoft SQL server using this code.

```
    public class ConnectionClass
    {
    String ip = "192.168.1.4";
    String classs = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";
    String db = "BlackForestProd";
    String un = "sa";
    String password = "P@ss123";

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public Connection CONN()
{
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    Connection conn = null;
    String ConnURL = null;
    try
    {
        Class.forName(classs);
        ConnURL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + ip + ";" + "databaseName=" + db + ";user=" + un + ";password=" + password + ";";
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnURL);
    }
    catch (SQLException se)
    {
        Log.e("ERRO", se.getMessage());
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
    {
        Log.e("ERRO", e.getMessage());
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("ERRO", e.getMessage());
    }
    return conn;
}
```

}

Used Connection class java file to get values from databases

```
    connectionClass = new ConnectionClass();
    Connection con = connectionClass.CONN();
                if (con == null) {
                    z = "Error in connection with server";
                } else {
                    Statement statement = con.createStatement();
                    rs = statement.executeQuery("select Name from tblAppcustomer where Mobile='" + userid + "'");
                    while (rs.next()) {
                        clientname = rs.getString("Name");
                    }
                }
```

Similarly I have data in my Oracle Db that I want to use in my Android project. Is there a similar way to do it . Or is there any other way. Im a beginner with Android.

Comment: Please remember that username and password included in an app can be extracted by everyone. hence everybody can connect to the database(s) and read/modify/delete data depending on the permissions of the used DB credentials...

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, but generally not recommended​ to access a database directly from an Android (or other mobile) app.
Among other the things, you can't guarantee that the phone will always be on the same network as the database, and you probably don't want to expose the database publicly.

The usual way to do this is to write a server-side app that will take requests from the mobile app, interact with the database, and return results to the mobile app. Using a REST interface is common, but not required.